# Question on Certificates (.CRT File)

Tags: certificates

I downloaded an existing certificate from a sandbox, so I have the .crt file.  Now I want to use this certificate in another sandbox.  Unfortunately Salesforce only allows you to import a .jks (Java Keystore) file.  I failed to generate one of these not knowing I would need it to import it in another Salesforce instance, so all I have is the .crt file.  Is there any workaround to getting the certificate uploaded back into Salesforce?

Comment: I don't think you can export private keys from Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

There's an excellent post here at stackexchange providing the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952274/how-can-i-create-keystore-from-an-existing-certificate-abc-crt-and-abc-key-fil

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had gone through the link and in addition to crt file, it is also asking for the key file. And we have crt and pem file. So, we need a way to create JKS file using CRT and PEM file. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Unfortunately link is not useful for my query. Thanks...